# `this` belongs to window object when triggering event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
$("body").on('click', 'ul#ajax-users-list>li', () => {
    console.log( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

This code returning `undefined`, because `$(this)` = `[Window]`.

How can i access data attributes for element, that triggered click event?

Comment: you can just use `this.id` if you are looking for attribute `id`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah true

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Before writing so, i console.log($(this)) and it returned `[Window]`. So, nope, you are not right!

Comment: @Src apologies, I missed the fact you're using an arrow function. I added an answer for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because you're using an arrow function, therefore the scope of the handler function will remain at the level of the definition. If you use a traditional anonymous function the logic will work fine:

```js
$("body").on('click', 'ul#ajax-users-list>li', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ajax-users-list">
  <li data-id="foo">click me</li>
</ul>
```

If you'd prefer to use the arrow function, then you would need to get the element that raised the event from the provided `event` argument instead of the `this` reference:

```js
$("body").on('click', 'ul#ajax-users-list>li', (e) => {
  console.log($(e.target).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ajax-users-list">
  <li data-id="foo">click me</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice one +1 bro

Comment: This could be improved by explaining that [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't bind their own `this` (and `arguments`, etc.).